# Cakephp 2.3.x Sending Files and forcing the download of a mp4 file

Tags: file, cakephp, download

I'm using cakephp 2.3.1

I want to force download a mp4 file per http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file

In my 'view' I have the following code which is correctly searching for the filename, and finding the file name, and displaying the download link:

```
<?php $filename = APP . 'webroot/files/' . $dance['Dance']['id'] . '.mp4'; 
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo $this->Html->link('DOWNLOAD', array('controller' => 'dances', 'action' => 'sendFile', $dance['Dance']['id'])); 
    } else {
    echo 'Coming soon: available April 16th';
    }
?>
```

When the user clicks on the link I want to force the download of the mp4 file.  In my controller I have the following code that doesn't work:

```
public function sendFile($id) {
    $file = $this->Attachment->getFile($id); //Note: I do not understand the 'Attachment' and the 'getFile($id)'
    $this->response->file($file['webroot/files/'], array('download' => true, 'name' => 'Dance'));
    //Return reponse object to prevent controller from trying to render a view
    return $this->response;
}
```

I don't understand 'Attachment' and the 'getFile()'

I'm getting the following error:
Error: Call to a member function getFile() on a non-object

What am I doing wrong and is there any other documentation I can be looking at to understand this better?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The line you don't understand is simply part of the example - it assumes the application has a model called `Attachment` and that it has a method called `getFile`. Since you don't have an `Attachment` model (or at least it isn't visible to the controller) you get a "call to member function on a non-object" error. That's not important though: all you need to worry about is providing a full system path to `this->response->file()`. In your example, you can probably get that by changing that line to:

```
$this->response->file(WWW_ROOT.'files/'. $id .'.mp4', array('download' => true, 'name' => 'Dance'));
```

You can get rid of the `$this->Attachment->getFile` line as it is irrelevant in your case.

Let me know if that helped!

Comment: I was also able to pass in a second variable on the public function so that it looked like this: `public function sendFile($id, $dance_name) {` which is freakn' amazing because it lets me auto create file names.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked. Can you accept the anser so I get some reputation? Cheers :)

Comment: Ok I assume all I have to do to accept the answer is click the check-mark and make it green?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function downloadfile($id= null) {        
  $this->response->file(APP.'webroot\files\syllabus'.DS.$id,array('download'=> true, 'name'=>'Syllubus'));
  return $this->response;     
}

<?php echo $this->Html->link('Syllabus', 
  array('controller' => 'coursesubjects',
    'action'=>'downloadfile',
    $courseSubject['CourseSubject']['subject_syllabus']));
?>
```

Comment: you dont need to return the response. `$this->autoRender = false` suffices.

Comment: Why are you using DS in one place, and then in the rest of the path you specify \. DS means directory separator and is set to the slash that you require on the system, so either use DS in place of all slashes, or use all hard-coded slashes.