# cakephp download link behind the image or media files not working

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a cakephp 2.x ... i have a form in which i am taking the file from the user and then i am saving fileinto the **app/uploads/userid** folder and saving the path into db ... i am successfully fetch the file and showing it to the user but now the problem is during  downloading.. i mean whenever user click the file link it will redirected the user to some unknown link

here is my code

public function uploadFile(){

```
    if ($this->request->isPost()){
        $this->loadModel('Audio');
        $file = $this->request->data['Audio']['file'];

    $idUser = $this->Auth->user('idUser');


        if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $id = String::uuid();
            $name =$file['name'];

            $folder_url = APP.'uploads/'.$idUser;
        if(!is_dir($folder_url)) {
            mkdir($folder_url);
        }
        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],  $folder_url.DS.$name);

            $this->request->data['Audio']['User_id'] = $idUser;
            $this->request->data['Audio']['filename'] = $file['name'];
            $this->request->data['Audio']['filesize'] = $file['size'];
            $this->request->data['Audio']['filemime'] = $file['type'];
            $this->Audio->save($this->request->data);


            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}



public function showfile(){
 $this->loadModel('Audio');
    $record = $this->Audio->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User_id' =>        $this->Auth->user('idUser'))));
    $this->set('file', $record);


}
```

on my **view page**

```
  <?php  echo $this->Html->link($file['Audio']['filename'], APP . DS . 'uploads' . DS . $file['Audio']['User_id'] . DS . $file['Audio']['filename'] . DS . $file['Audio']['filemime']);?>
```

here is the url after clicking the link

```
     /localhost/cakephp/media/C:/xampp/htdocs/cakephp/app//uploads/23/1011029_10152615392142588_1926259269_n.jpg/image/jpeg
```

i have tried every thing to make it work both nothing works out for me .. please i need help ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add like this with name of filename to click

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($file['Audio']['filename'], 'uploads' . DS . $file['Audio']['User_id'] . DS . $file['Audio']['filename'] . DS . $file['Audio']['filemime'], array('target' => '_blank')); ?>
```

for more understanding just go throw this [cakephp.org](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-HtmlHelper.html) link to understand html helper functionality

i hope it will useful to you.

Comment: thankyou it solves half the problem .. but dont why it is not downloading the file ... neither it is accessible through the url ... i dont know if i am doing right ... the file is in app/uploads/23/10......jpg... and now the url is after adding your link ...localhost/cakephp/media/uploads/23/1011029_10152615392142588_1926259269_n.jpg

Comment: just go http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html?highlight=media#MediaView and use media view to force download for your file just set params to your link

Comment: thankyou i got it working by by following this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210211/cakephp-2-3-x-sending-files-and-forcing-the-download-of-a-mp4-file